# Python 2.7 not searching folders inside of site-packages

Tags: python, python-module

I'm running Windows 7 x64. I've installed Python 2.7 32-bit into the default directory (C:/Python27).

I used Pip to install a few modules (e.g. social-auth), but when I try to import them, Python says there is no module with that name. For example, "import linkedin" results in an ImportError.

Google search suggests that the problem might be with a missing __init__.py, but all the subdirectories have an __init__.py (although I'm not sure what those files are supposed to contain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  Linkedin authentication backend, you should import this way,

`from social.backends.linkedin import LinkedinOAuth`

for OAuth2,
`from social.backends.linkedin import LinkedinOAuth2`